# How do I supply a specific instance of a class, to expose as my WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a class that implements a plugin for an existing application.

I also have exposed that class as a WCF service.  That part is working so far.  The problem I am running into is that the application I am plugging into creates the instance of my class that I want to use.

**Is there a way to pass an existing class instance to the WCF service host, to expose as a service endpoint?**

I know (or can figure out) how to make a singleton instance of a WCF service, but that still won't help me.  From what I can tell, the singleton instance will still be created and provided by WCF.

I have thought of other approaches, but I'd rather take this one if it is available to me.

Some code.  This is in the constructor of my plugin:

```
// Setup the service host
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MyService/");
this.serviceHost = new ServiceHost(this.GetType(), baseAddress);

// Add our service endpoint
// Todo: Is there somewhere around here that I can provide an instance?
//   Maybe in behavior somewhere?
this.serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(ITheInterfaceMyClassDerivesFrom),
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    ""
    );

// Add metadata exchange (so we see something when we go to that URL)
var serviceMetadataBehavior = this.serviceHost.Description.Behaviors
    .Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (serviceMetadataBehavior == null)
    this.serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());

this.serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMetadataExchange),
    new CustomBinding(new HttpTransportBindingElement()),
    "MEX"
    );
```

This is in the plugin's OnStartedUp method (called by the application I am plugging into):

```
serviceHost.Open();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the other constructor for `ServiceHost` if you want to do this - check out the MSDN docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx

```
public ServiceHost(
    Object singletonInstance,
    params Uri[] baseAddresses
)
```

Comment: I guess I just have to look :) Maybe I need more sleep.  Thanks!